# How can I set save and load a password with sharedPreference?

Tags: android, passwords, sharedpreferences

I am doing an android app which would save the password for the next time the user wants to use this app. when I try to run my application, the password is entered,but there is a pop-up said the application has stopped?

```
package com.wheresmyphone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


   public class Check extends Activity {


    String StringPreference;

    SharedPreferences preferences;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    final EditText preferences = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt12345);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText sharedPreferences = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt12345);
            String StringPreference = preferences.getText().toString();

        }



    });
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.check, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /**
     *   Method used to get Shared Preferences */

    public SharedPreferences getPreferences() 
    {

        return getSharedPreferences(null, 0);
    }
    /**
     *  Method used to save Preferences */
    public void savePreferences(String key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        String StringPreference =  sharedPreferences.toString();
        editor.putString("sharedString", StringPreference);
        editor.commit();
    }

/**
     *  Method used to load Preferences */
    public String loadPreferences(String key) 
    {
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences();
            String strSavedMemo = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
            return strSavedMemo;
        } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) 
        {
            Log.e("Error caused at  TelaSketchUtin loadPreferences method",
                    ">======>" + nullPointerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
    /**
     *  Method used to delete Preferences */
    public boolean deletePreferences(String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getPreferences().edit();
        editor.remove(key).commit();
        return false;
    }   

    {

}

}
```

Comment: preferences is null in this case

Comment: i believe u need to learn how to name variables. You are using the variable name `preferences` for both `SharedPreferences preferences;` & `final EditText preferences = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt12345);`. Try to keep different names for different types of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think you missed something at this point:

```
return getSharedPreferences(null, 0);
```

Look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

> Parameters
>   name
>   Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).

If you set "name" to null, he cant create a file.

Might be the solution, add this on top

```
private final String KEY_SHAREDPREFS = "tmpsharedprefs";
```

and then use it

```
return getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHAREDPREFS, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

See your are trying to get string from preference, first you have to get password from edittext like this code

```
EditText passwordText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt12345);
String password = passwordText.getText().toString();
```

and then store this password in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences as,

To Save:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "app_pref";
public static final String KEY_p_id = "KEY_test";

settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(Login_screen.KEY_test, values.get(0));
editor.commit();
```

To Remove:

```
editor.remove("KEY_test").commit();
```

To Get:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String TestId = settings.getString("KEY_test", null);
```